# django rest framework: Get url parameter value in a model property

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a Product model and one propery in it is "my_test_fn". This is called from my serializer. My requirement is, I want to do some calculations based on the filter passing through the url. How can I get the url parameter values in a model property?

I want to get "filters" value in my_test_fn

models.py

```
class Product(AbstractProduct):
     product_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     ##more fields to go

     def my_test_fn(self):
         filters = self.request.query_params.get('filters', None)
         return {"key":"value"}
```

serializer.py

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
       fields = ('id','product_id','sku', 'title', 'my_test_fn',)
```

views.py

```
class ProductDetailConfiguration(viewsets.ViewSet):

    lookup_field = 'product_id'


    def retrieve(self, request, product_id=None):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)[0]
        serializer = ProductConfigurationCustomSerializer(queryset, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

API url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/product-configuration/2FC2AA43-07F5-DCF4-9A74-C840FDD8280A?filters=5
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic belongs in the serializer, not the model. You can access it there via `self.context['request']`.

Comment: this can't be access in model? or can I pass it to model through serializer?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that your model knows about the request. This is the road to highly coupled code which is prone to failure. Let the view or serializer get the value and possibly pass it to the model but don't tie the model and the request

Comment: a bit more of an explanation of why and how would be nice

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is not possible (have the `my_fn` on the model itself).

You would need to use a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), so you will have access to the object, but to the request (and the various parameters of it) as well.